# What is the difference between "bill" and "political reform"?

Tags: differences

The definitions of reform and bill from Oxford Dictionaries:

> [Reform](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reform): the action or process of reforming an institution or practice.
>
> [Bill](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bill): a draft of a proposed law presented to parliament for discussion.

To me, political reform and bill sound very similar, but I would say that bills are rather smallish, while reforms tend to be bigger. However, I am not really sure, if I didn't also overlook something subtle. I would appreciate any constructive comment/answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Bill* is something very concrete, an actual document that, if approved by the legislature (and, in some systems, signed by the chief executive), will literally become a law, word-for-word. Bills can change during legislative debates, but eventually there will be a vote on the 'final version' of the bill, which is still a 'bill' until it is passed (and, possibly, signed 'into law'). Through that process, the actual literal text of the final version of the bill becomes a law.

*Reform* is a much broader concept, which may or may not have to do with laws and government. One can reform all kinds of institutions. A reform may well involve one or more new bills/laws, but could also/alternatively involve any of the following: changes in rules that are under the jurisdiction of regulatory agencies, new executive orders, and generally changes in policy at various levels of formality, and at various levels of government or other institutions.